# How to access an Objective C variable from different view controllers?

Tags: xcode, viewcontroller

I need to call:

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttons;
```

from viewcontroller x but be able to access and set the button colors from view controller y.   Basically I'm making a settings page that allows different color schemes.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Using properties seem like a bad idea here, you will end up with one property for every view you want to customize. Instead, implement a method that your other view controller can call (would  be good idea to make it a delegate method of that controller), make that method accept a parameter like color or theme or whatever and do all the customization in that method based on the parameter you get.

Comment: Can you explain that more?  I'm new to this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delegation.

Basically, viewcontroller y would be a delegate of viewcontroller x, and every time someone changes the settings page, you viewcontroller x would notify viewcontroller y of that change. X would notify Y like so:

```
[delegate doSomething withParameter: parameter]
```

Viewcontroller y would then perform certain methods with that parameter (the variable you're trying to pass).

There are a couple of other things involved, so you should read up on delegation

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass references to your view controller X when instantiating view controller Y:

```
ViewControllerY *viewController = [[[ViewControllerY alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerY" bundle:nil] autorelease];
viewController.viewControllerX = myRefToViewControllerX; //declare a property on your ViewControllerY
//show view controller Y
```